# How do I cast an object to an int in a Converter?

Tags: c#, wpf, converters

I give up, how do I cast this?

```
class AmountIsTooHighConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //int amount = (int)value;
        //int amount = (int)(string)value;
        //int amount = (int)(value.ToString);
        //int amount = Int32.Parse(value);
        //int amount = (int)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(int));
        //int amount = Convert.ToInt32(value);
        if (amount >= 35)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: //int amount = Convert.ToInt32(value); is not possible because there is already method in a namespace IvalueConverter, that will be overloading and it does not accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `Convert.ToInt32` or `Int32.Parse` should work... If they don't, then the value is definitely not an int ;) 
Try to put a breakpoint in your converter to watch the value, it might show you why it doesn't work

Comment: Parse won't even compile. Convert will work iff the object implements IConvertible.

Comment: Convert.ToInt32() and Int32.Parse would not parse *all* values like "2,000" ints with commas. I would suggest a try & a catch for a FormatException

Comment: thanks, there were two problems: value was actually a string and had to use System.Convert since the method is called Convert.

Comment: Since Int32.Parse(string), so and normally value is object there, so what can be done:: Danke schön

Answer (score 2):

If the value is actually a string object (with a content that represents an integer value), this gives the least overhead:

```
int amount = Int32.Parse((string)value);
```

The `Convert.ToInt32` should be able to handle most anything that is possible to convert to an `int`, like a string containing digits or any numeric type that is within the range that an `int` can handle.

Answer (score 1):

If the value is an object, `ToString()` is better to convert to string before parsing to `Int 
int amount = Int32.Parse(value.ToString());`

Comment: Could you please format your code by highlighting it and hitting Ctrl+K

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint at the opening parenthesis of your Convert method. Start your application in debug mode. When the breakpoint is hit analyze the actual type of *value*. Do the cast. If value is string cast it to string and then parse the result to get an integer. Run the program again. It should work this time.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is basically simple. Because the `IValueConverter` has itself a method called `Convert` you cannot simply us the `Convert` object just like that.

But if you add the correct prefix it works:

```
int amount = System.Convert.ToInt32(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int amount;
if(int32.TryParse((string)value,out amount)
{
   if(amount>=35)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
}
else
{
  return false;
}
```

This is safest way, I think!